# Upload Image to Server PHP Android

Tags: php, android

I am lost right now with trying to upload an image to my server. I am able  to take the picture and get my location on the Android device. I have the follow code to upload the file to the server:

```
    public Boolean postFunction(File image) {
    String tag = "postFunction";

    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(UPLOAD_URL);

    try {
        MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity();

        entity.addPart("type", new StringBody("photo"));
        entity.addPart("data", new FileBody(image));
        httppost.setEntity(entity);
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        Log.i(tag, "picture was uploaded " + response.toString());
        return true;

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        Log.e(tag, "Client: " + e.toString());
        return false;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(tag, "IO: " + e.toString());
        return false;
    }
}
```

I pass the image file to this function and it does the upload. However the error lies on the server end I believe.

Here is my PHP code:

```
      public function upload() {
        //$type = $this->input->post('type');
        //$data = $this->input->post('data');

        $base = $_REQUEST['data'];

        echo $base;

// base64 encoded utf-8 string

        $binary = base64_decode($base);

// binary, utf-8 bytes

        header('Content-Type: bitmap; charset=utf-8');

// print($binary);
//$theFile = base64_decode($image_data);

        $file = fopen('./test.jpg', 'wb');

        fwrite($file, $binary);

        fclose($file);

        echo '<img src=test.jpg>';
    }
```

The file gets touched but still remain blank. Am I missing something here? Please help, I tried Googling this but came up with different results that did not help me much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check one very good tutorial [here](http://blog.sptechnolab.com/2011/03/09/android/android-upload-image-to-server/).

Also try following code,

```
public class TryprojectActivity extends Activity {
    InputStream is;
    int pic_count = 0;
    Bitmap bitmap=null;
    FileInputStream in1,in2,in3;
    BufferedInputStream buf;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

        try {
            in1 = new FileInputStream("/sdcard/1.jpg");
        } 
        catch (FileNotFoundException e2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e2.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            in2 = new FileInputStream("/sdcard/2.jpg");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } 

    try {
        in3 = new FileInputStream("/sdcard/3.jpg");
    } 
    catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } 

    Bitmap bitmapOrg1 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in1);
    ByteArrayOutputStream bao1 = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmapOrg1.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, bao1);
    byte [] imagearray1 = bao1.toByteArray();
    String ba1=Base64.encode(imagearray1);

    Bitmap bitmapOrg2 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in2);
    ByteArrayOutputStream bao2 = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmapOrg2.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, bao2);
    byte [] imagearray2 = bao2.toByteArray();
    String ba2=Base64.encode(imagearray2);

    Bitmap bitmapOrg3 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in3);
    ByteArrayOutputStream bao3 = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmapOrg3.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, bao3);
    byte [] imagearray3 = bao3.toByteArray();
    String ba3=Base64.encode(imagearray3);

    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(3);

    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("image1",ba1));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("image2",ba2));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("image3",ba3));

    try{
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://helpdesk.cispl.com/upload_file.php");
        UrlEncodedFormEntity obj = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs);
        obj.setChunked(true);
        httppost.setEntity(obj);
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        //is = entity.getContent();
        httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown(); 
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        //CommonFunctions.writeLOG(ctx.getClass().toString(), e.toString());
        //CommonFunctions.showToast(ctx, "Unable to post captured image file: " +
        //e.toString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are running apache/php on a unix-based platform, make sure your apache server has write permissions to the directory it is trying to store the files in (as per your current code, the same directory the PHP script resides in).  As a quick test, do `chmod 0777 .` in the directory your script is in, and see if the uploaded image appears correctly.