# Uploading/saving selected image with Parse as backend

Tags: java, android, eclipse, parsing

Ok guys, so after spending one day trying to figure out how to upload an image to parse servers i finally decided to ask for your help. I didn't find any full example on how to do this.

What i want to be able to do is:

1. select image from gallery (already did that)
2. load into inageView (already did that)
3. at onClick event upload the selected picture to Parse servers (my problem)

Here you have my code snippet so far, but it's not working.

```
private static int RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE = 1;


mSubmitJobBTN.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            createJob(); //this method will send data to Parse

        }
    });


private void addJob(final String mUsernameText, String mJobNameText,
        String mJobDescriptionText, String mJobPriceText) {

    /*Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("picturePath");
    // Convert it to byte
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    // Compress image to lower quality scale 1 - 100
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
    byte[] image = stream.toByteArray();

    try {
        image = readInFile(path);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }*/

    ParseUser user = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();

    anunt.put("username", "andrei");
    anunt.put("jobName", mJobNameText);
    anunt.put("jobDescription", mJobDescriptionText);
    anunt.put("jobPrice", mJobPriceText);



    /*// Create a column named "jobPicture" and set the string
    anunt.put("jobPicture", "picturePath");

    // Create the ParseFile
    ParseFile file = new ParseFile("picturePath", image);
    // Upload the image into Parse Cloud
    file.saveInBackground();

    // Create a column named "ImageFile" and insert the image
    anunt.put("ImageFile", file);*/


    anunt.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
        public void done(ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Job succesfully posted!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();
                Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        JobsListActivity.class);
                in.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(in);
                finish();

            } else {

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Sign up error, please check all the fields",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }

    });
}


    public byte[] readInFile(String path) throws IOException {
    byte[] data = null;
    File file = new File(path);
    InputStream input_stream = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(
            file));
    ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    data = new byte[16384]; // 16K
    int bytes_read;
    while ((bytes_read = input_stream.read(data, 0, data.length)) != -1) {
        buffer.write(data, 0, bytes_read);
    }
    input_stream.close();
    return buffer.toByteArray();

}***strong text***

    @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK
            && null != data) {
        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
        String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                filePathColumn, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
        String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).edit()
                .putString("picturePath", picturePath).commit();
        cursor.close();

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.addJob_imageView);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use PHP or any server script to upload image from android to the server. Try the URL given below,

[Upload Image to Server PHP Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9543021/upload-image-to-server-php-android)

Answer (score 0):

this is the answer!

```
 ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    // Compress image to lower quality scale 1 - 100
                    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
                    byte[] imagez = stream.toByteArray();

                    ParseFile filez = new ParseFile("androidbegin.png",
                            imagez);

                    filez.saveInBackground();

                    imgupload = new ParseObject("Anunturi");

                    imgupload.put("JobPictureName", "AndroidBegin Logo");

                    imgupload.put("jobPicture", filez);

                    imgupload.put("jobPictureName", picturePath);
                    imgupload.put("username", mUsernameText);
                    imgupload.put("jobName", mJobNameText);
                    imgupload.put("jobDescription", mJobDescriptionText);
                    imgupload.put("jobPrice", mJobPriceText);
                    imgupload.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
                        public void done(ParseException e) {
                            if (e == null) {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                        "Job succesfully posted!",
                                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                Intent in = new Intent(
                                        getApplicationContext(),
                                        JobsListActivity.class);
                                in.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                                startActivity(in);
                                finish();
                            } else {
                                mGoogleNow
                                        .setVisibility(mGoogleNow.INVISIBLE);
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                        "An error occured",
                                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        }

                    });
                } else {
                    bitmap = null;
                    imgupload = new ParseObject("Anunturi");
                    imgupload.put("username", mUsernameText);
                    imgupload.put("jobName", mJobNameText);
                    imgupload.put("jobDescription", mJobDescriptionText);
                    imgupload.put("jobPrice", mJobPriceText);
                    imgupload.put("jobPictureName", "null");
                    imgupload.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
                        public void done(ParseException e) {
                            if (e == null) {
                                Toast.makeText(
                                        getApplicationContext(),
                                        "Job succesfully posted!",
                                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                Intent in = new Intent(
                                        getApplicationContext(),
                                        JobsListActivity.class);
                                in.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                                startActivity(in);
                                finish();
                            } else {
                                Toast.makeText(
                                        getApplicationContext(),
                                        "Error while posting job...",
                                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        }

                    });
```